# Join subdivide and un-subdivide objects

Tags: 3d-printing, subdivision-surface

I have a problem about joining 2 objects. One of them is subdivided, the other is not... I have to join them together, so I'm able to 3D-print them both in one object, but when I join them together, the ''un-subdivide'' objects turns subdivided, and it's impossible to get the object back in the right shape, so I wanna know if it's possible to join two objects whitout changing their separate ''subdivide-value''?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by applying subdivision surface modifier on subdivided object. Then the one you're joining to it, won't be subdivided.